# Did Sophocles write "Success is dependent on effort"?

Tags: quotes

I'm trying to find the source of the quote "Success is dependent on
effort." There are lots and lots of quotation sites that attribute it to
Sophocles. However, I have yet to find a *single* site that attributes
it to any particular *work* of Sophocles, or to a witness who wrote of
Sophocles having said it. The page on Wikiquote, which does require
citations, doesn't have it, and no one's brought it up on the talk page.

I suspect all these sites are just copying each other, and no one has
any idea whether it's actually from Sophocles or not. Are there any
classics scholars out there who can supply a reliable source or a
reliable refutation?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The quote is from *Electra*: for example, in [one translation](http://classics.mit.edu/Sophocles/electra.html),

> ELECTRA
>   Remember, nothing succeeds without toil.

---

There's a bilingual version of it here, [in English](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0188:card=920&highlight=succeeds),

> **Electra**
>   [945] Remember, nothing succeeds without toil.

And [in Greek](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0187:card=920),

> **Ἠλέκτρα**
>   ὅρα, πόνου τοι χωρὶς οὐδὲν εὐτυχεῖ. [945]

---

The [LSJ dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Greek%E2%80%93English_Lexicon) can help to give a more exact translation:

- The [dictionary entries for πόνου](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=po%29nou&la=greek#lexicon) suggest "toil", "labour", "hard work"; in Homeric language, the "toil of battle"; also "stress", "trouble", "suffering"; and "pain, especially physical".
- The [dictionary entries for εὐτυχεῖ](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=eu%29tuxei&la=greek#lexicon) suggest to be "prosperous", "fortunate", "well off", "successful".

εὐτυχεῖ was, apparently, also used in the sense of "fare thee well" in the close of letters, and on grave-stones.

---

[χωρὶς](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=xwris&la=greek#lexicon) ("without") and [οὐδὲν](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ouden&la=greek#lexicon) ("not one" or "none") are both negative words.

So the literal translation is some kind of double negative, as quoted above, for example (my translation):

> "Without toil, no success."

IMO this doesn't have quite the same several meanings as the English quoted in the OP.
My first thought, when I read the English phrase "depends on" in the OP, was,

> "the more effort, the more success"

The English phrase "dependent on" has two meanings:

- One meaning is a discrete, binary or 'categorical' relationship, i.e.

  > "not one without the other"
- A second meaning is a continuous function, i.e.,

  > "the more of one, the more of the other"

The English version of the phrase admits the second meaning as well as the first; but the Greek is only saying the first.

We do not know why it's a popular quote. Perhaps it suits someone's preconceptions or political agenda, e.g. "[the rich are rich because they worked harder than everyone else](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/anthony-w-orlando/the-rich-arent-rich-becau_b_4791626.html)".
IMO that meaning (comparative magnitude) isn't implied in the original, which is more like Yoda's "Do. Or do not." (There is no try.)

The original also has, IMO, something of a dualist meaning: "no success without effort".
In context, it seems almost a truism, (who knows, perhaps it was already a proverbial phrase in Sophocles' time):

> Chrysothemis
>   What do you urge, then, of those things that I am capable
>   of doing?
>
> Electra
>   That you be brave in executing what I recommend.
>
> Chrysothemis
>   If any good can be done, I will not refuse.
>
> Electra
>   [945] Remember, nothing succeeds without toil.
>
> Chrysothemis
>   I know it, and I will share your burden with all my
>   power.

Comment: Ah, well done! Or ["No joy is gained without some effort."](http://www.poetryintranslation.com/PITBR/Greek/Electra.htm), or ["Remember, without toil no plan may thrive!"](http://www.readbookonline.net/readOnLine/40301/) No wonder I couldn't find it, with such a wide variety of translations. Thank you.

Comment: "Without toil, no success" is very close to "no pain, no gain."

Comment: @MarkFoskey So it is. Buddhism recommends (in detail) "Right Effort" (*samma vayamo*), also "concentration" (or focus), and "zeal" -- also "exertion" (*sammappadhāna*) -- rather than "pain". See also Wikipedia, [No pain, no gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_pain,_no_gain): so I think that phrase may be misleading and maybe bad advice, "pain" a facile rhyme (an extrapolation from a Jane Fonda workout video). There's "renunciation" too in Buddhism, giving up something (I won't say "sacrifice" though), giving up what's seen to be unsatisfying/immoral/impermanent for something better instead.